# The necessity of having unimplemented methode in abstract class for sake of polymorphism?

Tags: python, oop, polymorphism

I don't see it is important to have it, because the real implementations will be implemented in each subclass anyway. Consider this code :

```
class Cat:
    def __init__(self, breed):
        self.breed = breed
    def sound(self): # having this or not does'nt make any difference
        pass

class Angora(Cat):
    def sound(self):
        print("miau")

class Scotish(Cat):
    def sound(self):
        print('meowww')

a = Angora('angora')
b = Scotish('scotish')

cats = [a, b]

for catt in cats:
    catt.sound()
```

I must be missing something right now because i am having difficulty to grasp this term.

Comment: Check out the `abc` module, it allows a variation of this that provides useful error-checking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

placing an empty method that will get overridden, no there is not much point, but if `Cat` was an actual abstract class and `sound` was a method that was **inforced** to be overriden, then there is a big benefit from it, for example:

```
import abc

class Cat(abc.ABC):
    def __init__(self, breed):
        self.breed = breed
    @abc.abstractmethod
    def sound(self): # having this as an abstract method DOES make a difference
        pass

class Scotish(Cat):
    def sonud(self):
        print('meowww')
```

Whether you noticed the **typo** or not, you will get this error when trying to initialize a `Scotish`:

```
>>> b = Scotish("scotish")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#12>", line 1, in <module>
    b = Scotish("scotish")
TypeError: Can't instantiate abstract class Scotish with abstract methods sound
```

So then before you get any weird ambiguous errors you are given what actually went wrong right away!

Also unlike simply `raise NotImplementedError` an abstract method can contain, well abstract code! Like an example of what the function might do, a great example would be `_collections_abc.Generator.throw`:

```
@abstractmethod
def throw(self, typ, val=None, tb=None):
    """Raise an exception in the coroutine.
    Return next yielded value or raise StopIteration.
    """
    if val is None:
        if tb is None:
            raise typ
        val = typ()
    if tb is not None:
        val = val.with_traceback(tb)
    raise val
```

This is not real code, this is not how a generator actually handles the `throw` method but it is a great *abstract* of how to at least handle the arguments!

Answer (score 2):

You need something like this, so if you forgot to implement the method in any subclass you will see an exception.

```
class Cat:
    def __init__(self, breed):
        self.breed = breed

    def sound(self):
        raise NotImplementedError('Should be implemented in subclass')
```

Also, it makes class interface cleaner.

Comment: You get an exception anyway if `Cat` doesn't have `sound`. It's an `AttributeError` that's about as informative as the error you've used.

Comment: @user2357112 see [my scenario with the typo](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37335195/5827215), in that case you would just get `AttributeError: 'Scotish' object has no attribute 'sound'` which can be really confusing if you don't see the typo, having something specifically tell you that it was not properly overridden in a subclass at least narrows down what went wrong.

Comment: @user2357112 `NotImplementedError` says that you forget to implement something, unlike `AttributeError`

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen: I find those error messages roughly equally confusing. One way is "why is Python saying this attribute doesn't exist when it clearly does", and the other is "why is Python saying I didn't implement this when I clearly did".

Answer (score 1):

Even if it isn't needed to make the code work, it helps to make the code self-documenting so it's easier to implement a Cat in the future. I also makes it possible to use introspection/reflection on a Cat object.
See also the motivations for adding 'proper' abstract base classes to python here: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3119/

Answer (score 0):

The thing that hasn't been said so far:

this is a crucial element of implementing sound solutions in regards of the [open closed principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open/closed_principle).

The key point is: typically, you are using abstract base classes in order to implement a certain behavior ... which should be the same for all sub classes. On the other hand, this "common" implementation might need to call sub-class specific methods in order to do its job.

Some pseudo code example:

```
abstract class Base:
   final foo():
      return "foo" + infoFromChild()

   abstract infoFromChild()
```

Then:

- you can call "foo()" on any object that inherits from Base
- you can override the empty abstract "infoFromChild" in each child class to the appropriate thing

But of course: such things make much more "sense" in "more static" languages like Java or C++. Within python, you might do things differently anyway.